# Error occur while fetching timeline of twitter

Tags: twitter, mgtwitterengine

When i run my code than following error occur.
I am using MGTwitterEngine for integrate twitter in my app.
Using this authentication process successfully done and i can successfully tweet but can not fetch my tweet on table view.

Please help me for fetching tweet timeline.

failed with error: Error Domain=HTTP Code=403 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 403.)"

Comment: Generally, a 403 means you sent a status update duplicated

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In the MGTwitterEngine.m

```
# define TWITTER_DOMAIN @ "twitter.com"
```

A,

```
# define TWITTER_DOMAIN @ "api.twitter.com / 1"
```

To change.